# How to get current url in contact form 7

Tags: forms, contact

I'm using Contact Form 7 in my wordpress installation. I need to somehow pass a hidden field with the current page url in the contact form hidden field. I tried their custom function and tried the short code, no luck.

```
wpcf7_add_shortcode('sourceurl', 'wpcf7_sourceurl_shortcode_handler', true);

function wpcf7_sourceurl_shortcode_handler($tag) {
    if (!is_array($tag)) return '';

    $name = $tag['name'];
    if (empty($name)) return '';

    $html = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name . '" value="http://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . '" />';
    return $html;
}
```

In the form edition I tried `[sourceurl thesource]`

Answer (score 7):

See this example on how to create and parse the shortcode in the contact form 7 to use it add `[current_url]`

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_form_tag_current_url' );
function wpcf7_add_form_tag_current_url() {
    // Add shortcode for the form [current_url]
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'current_url',
        'wpcf7_current_url_form_tag_handler',
        array(
            'name-attr' => true
        )
    );
}

// Parse the shortcode in the frontend
function wpcf7_current_url_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {
    global $wp;
    $url = home_url( $wp->request );
    return '<input type="hidden" name="'.$tag['name'].'" value="'.$url.'" />';
}
```

Also if its all about to get the URL in the email you dont need all of this. there is a special tag for the email `[_url]` [CF7 Special mail tags](https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/)

Comment: It forks for me if replace `$tag['name']` with `$tag['type']`:

`return '<input type="hidden" name="'.$tag['type'].'" value="'.$url.'" />';`

Answer (score 7):

according to Contact Form 7 documentation you need this:

[_url] — This tag is replaced by the URL of the page in which the contact form is placed.

reference: https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/

Comment: +1 for the common sense to read the docs :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use cf7 hidden field shortcodes + get parameters:
https://contactform7.com/hidden-field/
https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/

In the mail form I use such shortcodes to get these slugs

```
[hidden utm_source default:get]
[hidden utm_medium default:get]
[hidden utm_campaign default:get]
[hidden utm_content default:get]
[hidden gclid default:get]
```

It also works with their flamingo plugin.
And for mail template `[_url]` works very well.

Answer (score 2):

the form submit already send the container post then you just need to retrive it in and put it in the e-mail.
For that, try this code :

```
add_filter("wpcf7_posted_data", function ($wpcf7_posted_data) {

    $post = get_post($wpcf7_posted_data["_wpcf7_container_post"]);

    $wpcf7_posted_data["containerURL"] = get_permalink($post);


    return $wpcf7_posted_data;

});
```

And in the edition of the sent e-mail, you retrieve the URL with `[containerURL]`